# Why I can't reach to the content of open()

Tags: python, file

***what is the value?
what is the value?
what is the value?
what is the value?
what is the value?

---

'''

```
myfile = open('mytext.text')
"""
 if I print myfile it will not print
 its content I need to use read.() 
 function to read its content

"""
for line in myfile:
    print(line)
"""
  Now my question is why when I use this
  code it prints each line?? I didn't use 
  read.() function, how it reach to the
  content?? Please help me and thanks.
"""
myfile.close()
```

'''** did you understand? **

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to read from a file other than `f.read`. Iterating over a file loops over each line in a file.